# Is it safe to pass Google datastore keys to javascript as integers

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-datastore

I have some concerns about the autogenerated datastore keys.
The documentation claims that the result is a 64-bit integer. And for the [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Key) Google uses a `string` type to send the key.

From the other hand, Chris Ramsdale, Product Manager [says](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2013/05/update-on-datastore-auto-ids.html) that

> These IDs are large, well-distributed integers, but are guaranteed to be small enough to be completely represented as 64-bit floats so they can be stored as Javascript numbers or JSON.

But Chris made this post in 2013.

So I am confused by this discrepancy. Has anyone had any issues with representing autogenerated datastore IDs with JavaScript numbers?

Because otherwise, it is going to be pretty difficult to do the conversion in all HTTP handlers, both for parsing requests and returning responses.

Thank you!

Comment: A better way would be to use `urlsafe keys`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to [manually assign the key ids](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#kinds_and_identifiers), so even if GAE never generates ones javascript can't represent, it might be possible for it to be created another way. Best be safe and use strings.

Answer (score 0):

Autogenerated datastore IDs can be represented as JavaScript numbers without loss of precision. Nevertheless, Googles own APIs and libraries return ids sometimes as numbers and sometimes as strings depending on language and version. But so far I never had issues using numbers as an input type.